# Incrementing in a recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion

While working through tree-processing problems, I'm confused about best way to approach storing the number of instances a certain pattern has been observed.

For example, say I want to return the number of times of number in a Binary Search Tree is divisible by 2. I would walk through the tree recursively, check each key if it was divisible by two, and increment a counter.

Right now, the only way I can think to store this counter is by reference.
For example:

```
DivByTwo(node, counter) {
    DivByTwo(node.left, counter)
    DivByTwo(node.right, counter)

    if (node.key % 2 == 0) 
      counter ++
}
```

And after this is finished, the value of counter will be the number of keys divisible by 2. Is this a proper way to approach this problem? Is there a better way to capture this data without forcing the user to pass some variable by reference?

Comment: There are multiple ways you can produce the count. What problem are you trying to solve which is not already solved here? If you're looking for an opinion on how to go about the solution, you've come to the wrong site.

Comment: `return DivByTwo(node.left) + (node.key % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0) + DivByTwo(node.right)`

Comment: @Phylogenesis , thank you! That makes more sense... I guess the problem still arises when you need to determine increments based on other info you need to return, but this helps with a more basic case.

Comment: Partitioning an algorithm like this is something that only really comes with practice. At some point you learn how to reduce a problem to an end case and a reduction step (In this case, the empty tree has no even numbers, and every other tree reduces to the number of even numbers in the subtrees added to whether the value in the current node is even).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to avoid passing a ref parameter, although it requires being able to return a value (you don't include any type info, so I took a best guess at your types):

```
int DivByTwo(NodeType node){
    int result = DivByTwo(node.left) + DivByTwo(node.right);
    if(node.key % 2 == 0)
        result += 1;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You also need to check `node == null` and return 0, but this would be the canonical recursive method.

Comment: BTW - the reason your way (OP) with counter++ failed is because when you pass counter into divbytwo function it gets its own copy of counter that gets destroyed on exit

Comment: @Phylogenesis: The provided code didn't, I assume to avoid extra clutter?, so I just provided the basic solution to the mentioned problem, but yes, checking for null is going to be necessary in the actual code.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. I'm still fairly new to recursion, and keeping track of info is kinda bugging me out.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the counter by reference works and is a reasonable "small" solution.  If you want a more formal, more complex, but more adaptable to future needs solution consider implementing the visitor pattern which is described in many places on the net including [in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

Comment: Thanks for the info! That might be a little much for the current problem, but its something I'll look into for later on. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by returning the result:

```
int DivByTwo(Node *node) {
   if (node == null_ptr)
       return 0;

   return DivByTwo(node->left) + DivByTwo(node->right) + (node->key%2==0);
}
```